# I am not able to submit my form

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my angular form. I am using Template driven approach. When i am clicking ngSubmit i am calling a function but it is not getting called. I am trying to print something but it is not getting called.

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="loginUser(loginForm)">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" [(ngModel)]="username" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password" id="password" required>
          </div>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

        </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my TS file.

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
    })
    export class AppComponent  {
      username='';
      password = '';
      loginUser(form: NgForm) {
        console.log(form.value);
    }
    }

I have added formsModule to app.module.ts. In console is shows no error.
```

Comment: mark if the answer helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your button type as **`submit`**

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```